# BackgroundAudioAgent WP7: Fast-forward/rewind audio playback

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-process

I am currently developing a **WP7 Mango** using *Windows Phone Audio Playback Agent* Application which streams music (in form of MP3 and WMA files) from a web service. Everything works perfectly, but i can't seem to figure out how to fast-forward/rewind audio playback.
when i press and hold the next/previous buttons, the music stops, and it looks like its' seeking, but as soon as i let go, it reverts back to the position it was playing at before. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You have to react to the [`FastForward`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.useraction%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) or [`Rewind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.useraction%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) Action in the [`OnUserAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audioplayeragent.onuseraction%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) Callback.

**From Documentation:**

User actions do not automatically make any changes in system state; the agent is responsible for carrying out the user actions if they are supported.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I may be missing something. I pass the fastforward/rewind functions to the player, and it seems to try to do so, as it stops the playback, and the position seems to change. However, as soon as I let go of the control, it jumps back.

Answer (score 1):

did you change the position property of the player in your audio task.  You need to call FastForward and Rewind within these functions.  And you also need to handle the Seek action and within there set the player's Position property to the value of param (passed as an argument only when a seek is specified).  This will give you the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're trying to make a fast forwarding action then stop it, I guess you have to call the play (if the old state was playing) or pause (the other case) to stop the action of the fast forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you have to do:

```
 case UserAction.Seek:
 player.Position = (TimeSpan) param;
```